# Using C# on Linux with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

This is probably really simple, but I can't find the right article. I've been using c# for years, but I'm having a problem with writing in VS code without visual studio as a crutch, doing all the work for me.

I have a project.JSON with all the correct dependencies, I have a very basic class namespaced, and I can't reference it from my main.cs

```
using System;
using Characters;

namespace Combat{

    public class CombatGame
    {

        public static void Main(string []args){
        Character bob = new Character(1, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(bob.Health);

        }   
    }   
}
```

I'm getting an error type or namespace could not be found are you missing an assembly reference

I've seen a lot of articles on this, but none that directly relate to the issue I'm having. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace Characters
{
    class Character
    {
        public int Health {get; set;}
        public int Attack {get; set;}

        public Character(int health, int attack){
            this.Health = health;
            this.Attack = attack;
        }
    }   
}
```

EDIT

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Console Application",
  "authors": [ "" ],
 "tags": [ "" ],
 "projectUrl": "",
 "licenseUrl": "",
  "tooling": {
   "defaultNamespace": "Combat"
 },

  "dependencies": {

  },

  "commands": {
    "ems_dataparser": "ems_dataparser"
  },

  "frameworks": {
   "dnx451": {
     "dependencies": {
      "sqlite-net-pcl": "1.0.11" // add .NET 4.5.1 compatible packages here
     }
   },
   "dnxcore50": {
     "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "sqlite-net-pcl": "1.0.11" // add ASP Core compatible packages here
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what type of project are you using ?

Comment: just a basic console app

Comment: can you share your project.json ?

Comment: I added the file to my original post

Comment: please use View->Toggle Output and choose OmnisharpLog, look if there are any errors